# How to show uniform-convergence?

Tags: uniform-convergence

$f_n$ defined on $[0;1]$ by $f_n(x)=x^n$, $f_n(x)$ weakly-converges if $\forall x \in I$ $(f_n(x_0))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ have a finite limit.

And it goes without saying (tell me if that's too weak to prove) that  $\forall x\in [0,1],f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$

$f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ if $\forall\epsilon\ge 0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon$

An it exists such a N because $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}|x^n-f(x)|=0$

but I'm not quite sure about the uniform-convergence as far as I don't know what's hidding behind $f(x)$ alone without $n$.

Comment: If you include $1$ in the domain, then no, you do not get a pointwise limit of $0$. This fact is also key to the lack of uniform convergence: although you do have pointwise convergence to zero on $[0,1)$, it becomes very slow near $x=1$.